# Meu código esta com problema, ele adiciona +1 nos like e vai adicionando, invés do segundo click tirar 1

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#like-btn', function() {
    var tweet_id = $(this).data('tweet');
    var user_id = $(this).data('user');
    var counter = $(this).find('.likesCounter');
    var count = counter.text();
    var button = $(this);
    $.post('http://localhost/melfiz/core/ajax/like.php', {
      like: tweet_id,
      user_id: user_id
    }, function() {
      counter.show();
      button.addClass('unlike-btn');
      button.removeClass('like-btn');
      count++;
      counter.text(count);
      button.find('.olymp-heart-icon-o').addClass('.olymp-heart-icon');
      button.find('.olymp-heart-icon').removeClass('.olymp-heart-icon-o');
    });
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#unlink-btn', function() {
    var tweet_id = $(this).data('tweet');
    var user_id = $(this).data('user');
    var counter = $(this).find('.likesCounter');
    var count = counter.text();
    var button = $(this);
    $.post('http://localhost/melfiz/core/ajax/like.php', {
      unlike: tweet_id,
      user_id: user_id
    }, function() {
      counter.show();
      button.addClass('like-btn');
      button.removeClass('unlike-btn');
      count--;
      if (count == 0) {
        counter.hide();
      } else {
        counter.text(count);
      }
      button.find('.olymp-heart-icon').addClass('.olymp-heart-icon-o');
      button.find('.olymp-heart-icon-o').removeClass('.olymp-heart-icon');
    });
  });
};
'

                    '.(($likes['likeOn'] === $tweet->tweetID)? '<a class="post-add-icon inline-items" active data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"  id="unlink-btn" style=" cursor: pointer;">
                        <svg class="olymp-heart-icon"><use xlink:href="svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg#olymp-heart-icon"></use></svg>
                        <span class="likesCounter">'.$tweet->likesCount.'</span>
                    </a>' : '<a class="post-add-icon inline-items"  data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"  id="like-btn" style=" cursor: pointer;">
                        <svg class="olymp-heart-icon-o" ><use xlink:href="svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg#olymp-heart-icon-o"></use></svg>
                        <span class="likesCounter">'.(($tweet->likesCount > 0)? $tweet->likesCount : '').'</span>
                    </a>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse problema acontece porque quando você declara uma função para um evento de um elemento com um id especifico ele vai permanecer com essa função mesmo que o id dele mude, para ele alterar a função você precisaria executar novamente o seu codigo.

acho que a melhor opção para você seria fazer uma única função tanto para o like quanto para o deslike e fazer o controle do evento através de um atributo no botão

Fiz um exemplo utilizando o seu código.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#like-btn', function() {
   var tweet_id = $(this).data('tweet');
    var user_id = $(this).data('user');
    var counter = $(this).find('.likesCounter');
    var count = counter.text();
    var button = $(this);
    var curtir = $(this).attr('curtir');

    if(curtir == 1){
     $.post('http://localhost/melfiz/core/ajax/like.php', {
       like: tweet_id,
       user_id: user_id
     }, function() {
       counter.show();
       button.attr('curtir', '0');
       count++;
       counter.text(count);
       button.find('.olymp-heart-icon-o').addClass('.olymp-heart-icon');
       button.find('.olymp-heart-icon').removeClass('.olymp-heart-icon-o');
     });
    }else{
     $.post('http://localhost/melfiz/core/ajax/like.php', {
       unlike: tweet_id,
       user_id: user_id
     }, function() {
       counter.show();
       button.attr('curtir', '1');
       count--;
       if (count == 0) {
         counter.hide();
       } else {
         counter.text(count);
       }
       button.find('.olymp-heart-icon').addClass('.olymp-heart-icon-o');
       button.find('.olymp-heart-icon-o').removeClass('.olymp-heart-icon');
     });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="like-btn" curtir="1">Curtir</div>
```

Comment: Mas o id do botão `<a>` nunca muda... Só mudam as classes. E os cliques são identificados pelos ids.

Comment: Cara te amo, estou aprendendo Javascript ainda, mas obrigado demais de verdade.

Comment: Jefte acho que foi você, serio me ajudou demais slc.